# How long is a "rotation" on Mars?

Tags: warhammer-40k, mars, astronomy

I'm reading the novel *Mechanicum* in the Warhammer 40k universe. A group of engineers need to solve a complex problem in "seven rotations".

Is there a clear indication how long a rotation is? Is it the time Mars takes for a full revolution around its axis, i.e. a Mars day? Or is it the time Mars takes to rotate around the sun, i.e. a Mars year? And how long is it expressed in earthly standard days/hours?

Comment: I don't know anything about Warhammer, but usually in astronomy planets are said to rotate on their own axis, and revolve around the sun. So 'rotation' defines a day, and 'revolution' defines a year. A Martian day is about 24.5 hours.

Comment: Did it feel like they were under pressure? 7 Martian trips around the sun is 14 earth years. Not likely to add a lot of drama to the story.

Comment: @Jontia Actually I think Mars's orbital period is 687 days, or less than 2 earth years.

Comment: @DanielRoseman you're right. Make that 13.2 Earth years, much more dramatic :)

Comment: Argh sorry I misread, I didn't see the "7", I thought you were saying that a single trip around the sun was 14 years.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard astronomical terminology (which you have actually inverted in your question) is that a planetary *revolution* is one orbit around the sun, while a *rotation* is one turn of a planet about its axis.  The Warhammer 40K game and novels are generally pretty good about using astronomical terminology correctly; planetary years are described by as revolutions lasting certain numbers of Earth days.  So it seems that a "rotation" in the novel was meant to be a Martian day (approximately 24 hours, 39 minutes); this is further reinforced by the fact that seven Martian years is far too long a time to make time a significant pressure.

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of the standardized use of the words in astronomy. And a later passage where they're at the 23 hour of the seventh rotation working frantically to meet the deadline further supports your conjecture.

Comment: In particular, adepts of the Mechanicum live for technology. They would not use trivial and imprecise words like "days" if they can be technical